# Magento 2: VAT Configuration Issue

Tags: magento2, vat

I have two conditions If the user is from UK the VAT is 20% (That Part is done), But if He Has VAT No. then There will be 0% Tax Include in total Amount.

How This will be managed in Magento 2.